# Persian Calendar as Alternate Calendar in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

Since I am Helping to improve a SharePoint Site, I need to add Persian Calendar as an alternate calendar, just like Hijri which is one of the alternate calendars.
if any one have any clue or idea or even a  code to make Alternate Calendars I would appreciate.
Regards
Sh.Az

Answer (score 1):

This is the list of calendars in the current Preview:

[image]

Persian calendar is not supported in SharePoint OOTB. But you can check this codeplex link.May be this can help you

https://persiansharepoint.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks, but I found it before and it didn't match with our system which is 2010. I was looking for a OOB solution and surely it would not be easy! but thank you for answer.